# Need Help Compiling C Source Code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "Jordan";
    printf("hello, %s\n, s");
}
```

Does anyone know a way that I can get this native C source code to work? I'm having trouble getting it to compile and run.

Comment: 1) post the code here, rather than as a link to some picture.  2) post the actual error message from the compiler.  do not use header files that are not widely available/portable. (cs50.h)  (and when you get to be a knowledgeable C programmer.  you would realize the `string` type is actually `char *`,  Suggest using the actual C types, rather than some non-portable `string` type out of some non-portable header file.

Comment: I would suggest you reading the tutorial on Basic C programming.

Comment: I edited your question because the fact the you're using linux with xfce in a virtual machine has absolutely nothing to do with why you're code doesn't compile. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "native" C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second quote is in the wrong place. Try:

```
printf("hello, %s\n", s);
```